# Why can't a server provide guaranteed service with only bounded nondeterminsm?

Tags: concurrency, nondeterminism

The wikipedia page [Actor Model and Process Calculi History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model_and_process_calculi_history), presents the following claim:

> The semantics [of CSP] provided bounded nondeterminism unlike the Actor model with unbounded nondeterminism. However, with bounded nondeterminism is [sic] impossible for a server to guarantee service to its clients, i.e., a client might starve.

However, there is no citation provided for the claim. Carl Hewitt makes the same claim [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7erJ1DV_Tlo&t=1388s), so it's not a mistake by a wikipedia author. Can anyone provide the source (or their own proof) of this assertion?